# How to open jQuery dialog on html CheckBox checked(using jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, checkbox

I want to popup a jQuery dialog when a html checkbox is checked. I'm using following code. But it's not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#chkBoxHelp').click(function () {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $("#txtAge").dialog();
            }
        });
    });
```

And the html is as below:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkBoxHelp"/>
<div id="txtAge" style="display: none;">Age is something</div>
```

Please help me.

Also I want to uncheck the checkBox when popup will be closed. Checkbox is in a jQuery popup box. I need to open another popup on checkbox checked.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Here you go -> http://jsfiddle.net/x4CM3/1/

Comment: Hi Adeneo, thanks for your response. It's working fine in asp page. I forget to mention that the checkbox is in a jQuery popup. I need to open another popup on checkbox checked. I've also updated the question. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`open`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-open) and [`close`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close) methods and [`close`](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#event-close) event.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#chkBoxHelp').click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#txtAge").dialog({
                close: function () {
                    $('#chkBoxHelp').prop('checked', false);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $("#txtAge").dialog('close');
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/V9zMx/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. It's working fine in asp page. I forget to mention that the checkbox is in a jQuery popup. I need to open another popup on checkbox checked. I've also updated the question. Please help.

Comment: @TempExpt so you have to opened popup at the same time? Is something in modal?

Comment: Thank you very much. Thank a lot. It's working fine. I'm marking it as solved.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, also closing if the checkbox is clicked again.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var the_checkbox = $('#chkBoxHelp');
    the_checkbox.click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $("#txtAge").dialog({
                close: function () {
                    the_checkbox.prop('checked', false);
                }
            });
        } else {
            $("#txtAge").dialog('close');
        }
    });
});
```

### Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/VSDQf/)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. It's working fine in asp page. I forget to mention that the checkbox is in a jQuery popup. I need to open another popup on checkbox checked. I've also updated the question. Please help.

Comment: @TempExpt, so you mean that at some time you will have 2 dialogs open?

Comment: not at the same time. when i click on a button a div is opening as a popup. the div contains a checkbox. now i want another popup on checkbox checked.

Comment: @TempExpt, you mean close the dialog with the checkbox and open a new one?

Comment: no. when i close the 2nd dialog, then checkbox(in first dialog) will be unchecked. I got solution from Irvin below. Thank you.